# Add title attribute to elementor carousel images

Tags: wordpress, carousel, elementor

I'm trying to create a WordPress website using Elementor. I'm using the image carousel widget to create a slider. The images I use all have alt text and a title. The problem is that when I check the HTML code of my page none of the images in the carousel contains the title attribute.

I used this code snippet to try to fix the problem:

```
 function isa_add_img_title( $attr, $attachment = null ) {

 $img_title = trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) );

 $attr['title'] = $img_title;
 $attr['alt'] = $img_title;

 return $attr;
 }
 add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','isa_add_img_title', 10, 2);
```

It works with all website images except carousel images.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to figure out how elementor constructs the carousel. What does the code say?

Comment: Does `title="<?php echo esc_attr( $img['alt'] ); ?>"` or alike is set in the template used by the carrousel so it can produce that attribute?